# The mouse scroll for the main content is not working when I open the side-drawer. How do I go with this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

On opening the sidebar the main content scroll does not work. Also some fields such as select options, search bar do not work when the sidebar is open. I have added the main content in the routes from where it is being loaded. The scroll, above listed functions work  fine when the side-drawer is closed. I am relatively new to material ui + react and tried to workaround with some tips from other sources but I am stuck with this for a long time.

```
  <>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <AppBar
          sx={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(19, 71, 129)" }}
          position="fixed"
          className={classes.appBar}
        >
          <Toolbar align="center">
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              onClick={handleMenuClick}
              edge="start"
              className={clsx(classes.menuButton)}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="temporary"
          open={open}
          transitionDuration={{
            enter: transitionDuration,
            exit: transitionDuration,
          }}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
          }}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              sx={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}
              onClick={handleMenuClick}
              edge="start"
              className={clsx(classes.menuButton)}
            >
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
          <div className={classes.drawerContainer}>
            {/* //Drawer Items */}

            <DrawerItems open={open} isAdmin={isAdmin} />
          </div>

          {/* Logout */}

          <LightTooltip title="Logout" placement="top">
            <IconButton
              sx={{ marginTop: "auto" }}
              onClick={handleLogout}
              color="error"
            >
              <ExitToAppIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </LightTooltip>
        </Drawer>
        {/* Routes for drawer components */}
        <main
          className={clsx(classes.content, {
            [classes.contentShift]: open,
          })}
        >
          <Routes>
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="employees" element={<Employees />} />
            <Route path="payroll" element={<Payroll />} />
            <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
            <Route path="leaves" element={<Leaves />} />
            <Route path="leavesemp" element={<LeavesEMP />} />
            <Route path="empattendance" element={<EMPAttendance />} />
            <Route path="hrattendance" element={<HRAttendance />} />
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </Box>
    </>
```

This is the style

```
drawerContainer: {
    overflow: "auto",
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: transitionDuration,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: transitionDuration,
    }),
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
  },
```

Comment: assign overflow: "auto" to your body

Comment: @AliM.Sadeghi I did check it with that. Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hurry so I used a "persistent" mui drawer variant and solved the problem. I will still be looking to solve this particular problem though.